# Is there anyway to set path for Azure Installation?

Tags: azure, centos, azure-devops, oozie

Recently, I running script on oozie by command `az storage blob list -c`.
However, there is an error said

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.azure'

from checking azure path, it's locates in '/home/user/.azure'
but! when I ssh directly to server and use `az storage blob list -c`
gave no error and also no clue of path.

Any suggestion would be great! I really appreciate

Thanks!

Comment: `-c` is for specifying the container name in your storage account. What parameter did you provide? Remember that blob storage is not the same thing is a local folder on a hard drive. Where does `/home/.azure` exist? Is that a virtual folder within a "home" container in storage? Please edit to clarify your question.